# Align custom radio button and label as columns

Tags: css, radio-button

I'm trying to align my custom radio button as its own column next to a `label` element, which contains multiple `span`s. It would be easy to achieve with a default radio button, but since the custom style is applied to the `label:before`, it doesn't behave the same.

```
<div class="sp-package-show">
  <input type="radio" name="" value="">
  <label>
    <span>Title</span>
    <span>Date</span>
  </label>
</div>

[type="radio"] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

label {
    cursor: pointer;
}

[type="radio"] + label {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

[type="radio"] + label:before {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.1em;
    height: 1.1em;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    border-radius: 1em;
    // border: 0.15em solid $gray;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray;
    margin-right: 0.75em;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.05em gray;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/mwRdbx

Comment: Are the label and spans contained by a wrapping element?

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, I've updated my post with the container for each radio section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the `label` `display: flex`, then wrap your `span`s in another element, so that the flex children of `label` are the `:before` element and the element that wraps your `span`s. That will put them in adjacent columns. And to have the spans be on their own line, use `display: block`.

```css
[type="radio"] {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

[type="radio"] + label {
  margin-left: 1px;
  display: flex;
}

[type="radio"] + label:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1.1em;
  height: 1.1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px gray;
  margin-right: 0.75em;
}

[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.05em gray;
  background-color: gray;
}

span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="" value="">
<label>
<div class="meta">  <span>Title</span>
  <span>Date</span>
  <span>Date</span>
  <span>Date</span>
  <span>Date</span>
  <span>Date</span>
  <span>Date</span>
  </div>
</label>
```

Comment: When I run your snippets, both `span`s are still on the same line

Comment: @MarioParra what do you mean exactly by "align as columns" then? I assumed you just meant vertically aligned. You don't want the spans on the same line/row?

Comment: The radio button should be on one column to the left, and the `label`/both `span`s should be in the right column, above each other. Basically, I don't want any of the `span`s to wrap under the radio button.

Comment: @MarioParra wow, that level of specificity isn't something I would assume from your post. You should update the post with those details. Can you draw a picture of what you're looking to achieve?

Comment: @MarioParra is this what you're trying to do? https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/MoJWoK

Comment: I was drawing a picture, but yes! This! Thanks so much. Looking over it now to understand the solution

Comment: @MarioParra ah great. I can explain it if you want. With that, you can also use `align-items` on the label to vertically align if you want.

Comment: @MarioParra updated my answer and added an explanation.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again!

Comment: The problem I'm experiencing, though, is that clicking the radio button doesn't check it (tabbing to it and hitting Space does check it). Could this be related to the new structure? https://codepen.io/ourcore/pen/LLxVVE

Comment: @MarioParra you can't check the `input` if it's hidden. You can give the `input` an `id` and use the `for` attribute on the `label` to link it to the `input` so that when you click on the `label` it checks the `input` https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/owBXjX

Comment: Just realised this too. Thanks again

Comment: @MarioParra you bet :)

Comment: To who ever downvoted my answer, do you  mind providing a reason as to why you think my answer isn't helpful for OP?

Comment: I think it was downvoted during the original answer, before I clarified what I was trying to achieve

Comment: @MarioParra that's what I'm assuming, too. Oh well :) A risk we take answering questions that aren't spelled out clearly. But I'm just interested in helping, so if the first stab isn't it, with some clarification we can figure it out (like we did). I tend not to downvote unless the answer is way off, not helpful at all, and I always give a reason so that the person can correct the answer and I'll remove the downvote and OP gets a good solution.